# Combine two Group Bys that work on two date fields?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that returns the weekly counts for items in a table for the last 5 weeks. My goal is to combine two Group Bys for 2 separate date fields that share the same week.

The following query:

```
SELECT datepart(week, Date1) AS WeekNum, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Table
WHERE (Date1 >= DATEADD(week,-5, GETDATE())
      OR
      (Date2 >= DATEADD(week,-5, GETDATE())
)

GROUP BY datepart(week, Date1), datepart(week, Date2)
ORDER BY WeekNum DESC
```

Returns:

```
-----------------
| Week | Count  |
-----------------
|   1  |  10    |
-----------------
|   2  |  20    |
-----------------
|   3  |  30    |
-----------------
|   4  |  40    |
-----------------
|   5  |  50    |
-----------------
| NULL |  10    |
-----------------
| NULL |  20    |
-----------------
| NULL |  30    |
-----------------
| NULL |  40    |
-----------------
| NULL |  50    |
-----------------
```

Where I want it to return:

---

```
| Week | Count  |
-----------------
|   1  |  20    |
-----------------
|   2  |  40    |
-----------------
|   3  |  60    |
-----------------
|   4  |  80    |
-----------------
|   5  |  100   |
-----------------
```

Where both Date Group Bys are combined for the week.

How can I write the query?

Comment: I would group by week of each date in seperate queries, union and sum.

Comment: Will `Date1` and `Date2` falls on different week ?

Comment: @Squirrel If any of them fall in a week outside those 5 weeks scrap it

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as
(SELECT coalesce(datepart(week, Date1), datepart(week, Date2)) AS WeekNum
FROM Table
WHERE (Date1 >= DATEADD(week,-5, GETDATE())
      OR
      (Date2 >= DATEADD(week,-5, GETDATE())
)
select weekNum, count(*) as count
from data
GROUP BY weekNum
ORDER BY WeekNum --DESC
```